# For loop error in C#

Tags: c#

Im trying to run this for loop to fill a certain column in a datagrid view but give the error of "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

```
              for (int i = 0; i < noofloops; i++)
              {
                  dgroute.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value ="Hey";
              }
```

I got some new addition info...here is the whole code what im really trying to do is that i want to get the date of the datepicker1 to datepicker2. ive subtract the date1 and date2 to get the difference to the 2 dates and for loop it in order to display all the specific date between date1 and date2 in the datagridview

```
 private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              DateTime A = dtFrm.Value;
              DateTime B = dtTo.Value;
              TimeSpan ts = B - A;
              int days = ts.Days;




                  for (int i = 0; i < dgroute.Rows.Count; i++)
                  {

                      dgroute.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value ="Hey";

                  }

              }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried?  How have you approached debugging this problem thus far?

Comment: noofloops count is larger than dgroute.Rows count

Comment: either noofloops is more than Rows.Count or Cells is empty for certain index

Comment: You said in your comments your datagrid is empty at first.  You want to add rows instead of trying to modify non-existent ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your loop to this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgroute.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    dgroute.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value ="Hey";
}
```

Comment: the datagridview is empty at first..

Comment: if the datagridview is empty how are you going to edit rows/cells that dont exists, you may want to add some rows first

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
          for (int i = 0; i < noofloops && i < dgroute.Rows.Count; i++)
          {
              dgroute.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value ="Hey";
          }
```

You're most likely indexing past the end of dgroute.Rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgroute.Rows.Count -1; ++i)
{
    dgroute.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value ="Hey";
}
```